# ¿Por qué no muestra el mensaje cifrado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Estoy siguiendo un proyecto en donde el objetivo del codigo es poder cifrar o descifrar un mensaje usando un key de entrada y los simbolos que considere necesarios, dentro de ella estan los signos del alfabeto, para ello tambien estoy usando una libreria cryptomath que se encarga de hacer gcd(maximo comun divisor y el findModInverse(inverso multiplicativo modular), el problema que me arroja mi codigo es varios errores que tienen su origen en no reconocer la variable de cadena llamada SYMBOLS y que pongo justo al inicio para que pueda funcionar pero hasta ahora no he tenido buenos resultados.

```
import sys, pyperclip, cryptomath, random
SYMBOLS=''' !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_´abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'''

def main():
    myMessage='''A computer would deserve to be called intelligent if it could
    deceive a human into believing that it was human.'''
    myKey = 2023
    myMode = 'encrypt'

    if myMode == 'encrypt':
        translated = encryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
    elif myMode == 'decrypt':
        translated = decryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
    print('Key: %s ' % (myKey))
    print('%sed text:' % (myMode.title()))
    print(translated)
    pyperclip.copy(translated)
    print('Full %sed text copied to clipboard.' % (myMode))


def getKeyParts(key):
    keyA=key//len(SYMB0LS)
    keyB=key % len(SYMBOLS)
    return(keyA,keyB)

def checkKeys(keyA, keyB, mode):
    if keyA==1 and mode == 'encrypt':
        sys.exit('The affine cipher becomes incredible weak when key A is set to 1. Choose different key.')

    if keyB==0 and mode == 'encrypt':
        sys.exit('The affine cipher becomes incedibly weak when key B is set to 0. Choose a different key.')

    if keyA < 0 or keyB < 0 or keyB > len(SYMBOLS)-1:
        sys.exit('Key A must be greather than 0 and B must be between 0 ans %s.' % (len(SYMBOLS)-1))

    if cryptomath.gcd(keyA,len(SYMBOLS)) !=1:
        sys.exit('Key A (%s) and the symbol set size (%s) are not relatively prime. Choose a different key.' % (keyA, len(SYMBOLS)))

def encryptMessage(key, message):
    keyA, keyB = getKeyParts(key)
    checkKeys(keyA, keyB, 'encrypt')
    ciphertext = ''
    for symbol in message:
        if symbol in SYMBOLS:
            symIndex = SYMBOLS.find(symbol)
            ciphertext += SYMBOLS[(symIndex * keyA + keyB)% len(SYMBOLS)]
        else:
            ciphertext += symbol
    return ciphertext

def decryptMessage(key, message):
    keyA, keyB = getKeyParts(key)
    checkKeys(keyA, keyB, 'decrypt')
    plaintext =''
    modInverseOfKeyA = cryptomath.findModInverse(keyA, len(SYMBOLS))

    for symbol in message:
        if symbol in SYMBOLS:
            symIndex = SYMBOLS.find(symbol)
            plaintext += SYMBOLS[(symIndex-keyB)*modInverseOfKeyA % len(SYMBOLS)]
        else:
            plaintext += symbol
    return plaintext

def getRandomKey():
    while True:
        keyA = random.randint(2,len(SYMBOLS))
        keyB = random.randint(2,len(SYMBOLS))
        if cryptomath.gcd(keyA, len(SYMBOLS)) != 1:
            return keyA*len(SYMBOLS)+keyB

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

'''Y aqui añado la libreria que cree: el cryptomath:'''

```
def gcd(a,b):
    while a!=0:
        a, b = b % a, a
    return b

def findModInverse(a,m):
    if gcd(a,m)!=1:
        return None
    u1, u2, u3 = 1,0,a
    v1, v2, v3 = 0,1,m
    while v3 != 0:
        q = u3//v3
        v1, v2, v3, u1, u2, u3 = (u1 - q * v1), (u2 - q * v2), (u3 - q * v3),v1,v2,v3
    return u1 % m
```

'''Y tambien adjunto el mensaje de error que me sale:'''

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PYTHON\affineCipher.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\PYTHON\affineCipher.py", line 11, in main
    translated = encryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
  File "E:\PYTHON\affineCipher.py", line 40, in encryptMessage
    keyA, keyB = getKeyParts(key)
  File "E:\PYTHON\affineCipher.py", line 22, in getKeyParts
    keyA=key//len(SYMB0LS)
NameError: name 'SYMB0LS' is not defined
```

Comment: Recuerda incluir los mensajes de error EN la pregunta. Ve a [edit] y añádelos.

Comment: En esta línea `keyA=key//len(SYMB0LS)` parece haber un carácter en `SYMB0LS` que no es una `O`, parece un `0`...

Comment: claro tambien hay numeros dentro de SYMBOLS

Comment: Dentro de la variable no, en el propio nombre de la variable...

Comment: MUCHAS MUCHAS GRACIASSSSSS... ES VERDAD... DISCULPEN EN VERDAD LA MOLESTIA SOY CASI PRINCIPIANTE EN ESTO Y ESTABA HECHANDO A PERDER TODO EL CODIGO... GRACIAS Fransico Javier